# show that $\{S_n\} $ converges $S_n= \frac{r^n}{1+r^n} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Using the non-increasing/ non decreasing theorem , show that $\{S_n\} $ converges
$$S_n= \frac{r^n}{1+r^n} $$
With $r>0$

The theorem to apply:

> > if $\{S_n\}$ is non-decreasing , then $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n = sup\{S_n\}$.
> >
> > If $\{S_n\}$ is non-increasing, then $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n = inf\{S_n\}$

Nonincreasing/decreasing?
Considering 
$$ S_{n+1} = \frac  {r^{n+1} }    {1+r^{n+1} }$$
$$ S_{n+1} = \frac  {r \cdot r^n }    {r \cdot (\frac{1}{r} +r^n})  $$
$$ S_{n+1} = \frac  { r^n }    {\frac{1}{r} +r^n }  $$

When $r \geq 1$
$$1 \geq \frac{1}{r}$$
$$1+ r^n     \geq  \frac{1}{r} + r^n$$
$$S_n = \frac{r^n}{1+ r^n} \leq      \frac{r^n}{     \frac{1}{r} + r^n      } = S_{n+1} $$
It shows that the sequence is non decreasing by definition

It follows that by the theorem stating that if $S_n$ is non-decreasing, we have
$$ \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n = sup\{S_n\}$$

Considering  that 
$$ S_n= \frac{r^n}{1+r^n} < \frac{r^n}{r^n} = 1 => sup\{S_n\}=1 =  \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n$$

For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an integer $N$ such that $| S_n – 1| < \epsilon$ with $n \geq N$

Considering
$$ | S_n – 1| = |\frac{r^n}{1+r^n} -1 |= |- \frac{1}{1+r^n} | = \frac{1}{1+r^n} < \frac{1}{r^n}<\epsilon$$
Let N be such that 
$$ \frac{1}{r^N} < \epsilon$$
$$\frac{1}{\epsilon} < r^N$$
$$\log \frac{1}{\epsilon} < N \cdot \log r$$
$$N > - \frac{\log \epsilon}{log r}$$
For every $\epsilon >0$, there is $n\geq N > - \frac{\log \epsilon}{\log r}$ s.t.
$$|S_n -1| < \epsilon$$
It follows that when $r \geq 1$, $S_n$ converges.
.

Then there is the case  when $ 0 < r \leq  1$ ....

.

I am unsure about those results. My question is about  $N > - \frac{\log \epsilon}{\log r}$ and $ n\geq N > - \frac{\log \epsilon}{\log r}$ Is my method correct?  can this be negative? I think I have some difficulties with the conceptual understanding when framing N. Does $N$ have to be a value or is a bound enough?

Comment: Your algebra will become easier if you rewrite as $S_n=\frac{1}{1+r^{-n}}=(1+r^{-n})^{-1}$.

Comment: You need to watch out for the case when $r=1$. Then $S_n$ is always $\frac{1}{2}$ so clearly convergent, but not to 1. Distinguish the cases $r>1$, $r=1$ and $0<r<1$.

Comment: Thx for this. I did not see that one. So It should have three cases: $r>1$, $r=1$, and  $0<r<1$

Comment: @1524 Thanks for the edit to my post. You are absolutely correct that I intended for $r>1$ though I appear to have slipped up and did not write this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks correct to me but could be condensed and reworded a bit. Here is how I would do it:

---

Let $S_n = \frac{r^n}{1+r^n}=\frac{1}{1+r^{-n}}$ so that $S_n$ is clearly non-decreasing for $r\ge 1$ since $r^{-n}$ is non-increasing
Then $\sup(S_n)=\lim\left( \frac{1}{1+r^{-n}}\right) =1$
We now wish to prove that $S_n$ converges to $1$ when $r>1$; to this end,  let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, and let $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $N> \frac{\log(1/\epsilon)}{\log(r)} \implies \frac{1}{r^N} < \epsilon$
Then, for all natural numbers $n \ge N$,
$$|S_n - 1| = \left|\frac{1}{1+r^{-n}} - 1\right| = \left|\frac{-r^{-n}}{1+r^{-n}}\right| = \frac{r^{-n}}{1+r^{-n}}=\frac{1}{1+r^n}<\frac{1}{r^n} <\frac{1}{r^N}<\epsilon$$
And so we conclude that $S_n$ converges to $1$ .

---

> Is my method correct?

As far as I can tell, yes it is.

**Edit:** as `@1524` notes,this argument only works for $r > 1$ and **not** for $r \ge 1$. At the point $r=1$ we just have a sequence with all terms $\frac{1}{2}$ which trivially converges to $\frac{1}{2}$

> can this be negative?

Note that $\frac{-\log(\epsilon)}{\log(r)} = \frac{\log(1/\epsilon)}{\log(r)}$ is only negative $\epsilon > 1$ in which case ***any*** positive value for $N$ will suffice.

> Does $N$ have to be a value or is a bound enough?

$N$ is definitely a value, since $N \in \mathbb{N}$. It is also a lower bound on $n$, since $n \ge N$.